# wifi adapter not found ubuntu 20.04 dmesg | grep iwl, fails to wake nic

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, hp

I recently clean installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my HP probook 655 G2. The problem is that at first the wifi adapter is working but after a while it says it couldn't find WiFi adapter. I reboot and the  wifi adapter is working, but after a while i get the same problem, Wifi adapter not found.

I ran lshw -C network and lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list at the moment when the wifi adapter was working and when it didn't. These are the results.

EDIT: 4th code block under " wifi adapter not found" , dmesg | grep iwl gives me a big error message fails to wake nic, not sure what I  should do. Since I didnt had this problem with windows I dont think it is a hardware problem.

EDIT: I did this: sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms. Didnt solve the problem

**Wifi adapter is working**

```
sebastiaan@sebastiaan-HP-ProBook-655-G2:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 98:e7:f4:2c:71:67
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:36 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0c04000-d0c04fff memory:d0c00000-d0c03fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 61
       serial: 7c:b0:c2:bc:f4:b7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-40-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 ip=192.168.2.5 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:39 memory:d0b00000-d0b01fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

$lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev c5)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Platform Security Processor
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Audio Dummy Host Bridge
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 49)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4a)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

$ dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    4.167072] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.199565] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.199584] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    4.202084] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1654887522.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.316658] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    4.337464] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.340930] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    4.348813] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 7c:b0:c2:bc:f4:b7
[    4.409553] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.021100] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    7.779168] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    7.859630] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    7.860830] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[   30.859876] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   30.938307] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[   30.939770] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

**Wifi adapter not found**

```
sebastiaan@sebastiaan-HP-ProBook-655-G2:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 15
       serial: 98:e7:f4:2c:71:67
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:34 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0c04000-d0c04fff memory:d0c00000-d0c03fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 61
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d0b00000-d0b01fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:522a] (rev 01)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

$lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wani [Radeon R5/R6/R7 Graphics] (rev c5)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:02.5 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Host Bridge
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Platform Security Processor
00:09.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Carrizo Audio Dummy Host Bridge
00:09.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Audio Controller
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 20)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 49)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 49)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 4a)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 60h-6fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 (rev 61)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

$ dmesg | grep iwl

```
[    4.127375] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.138916] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.138929] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    4.140438] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.1654887522.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.219643] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    4.235949] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    4.239973] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    4.245793] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 7c:b0:c2:bc:f4:b7
[    4.306483] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    5.210743] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    8.032507] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.142328] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    8.143533] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
[  982.218889] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  982.219025] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending TXPATH_FLUSH: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  982.219032] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to send flush command (-5)
[  982.237288] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  982.237397] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending SCD_QUEUE_CFG: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  982.237403] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to disable queue 2 (ret=-5)
[  982.255670] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  982.255779] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending REMOVE_STA: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  982.255787] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to remove station. Id=2
[  982.255792] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed sending remove station
[  982.274026] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  982.274198] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending BINDING_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  982.274207] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to send binding (action:3): -5
[  982.292477] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  982.292597] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending PHY_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  982.292605] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: PHY ctxt cmd error. ret=-5
[  982.310861] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  982.310989] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MAC_PM_POWER_TABLE: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  982.329274] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  982.329453] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MAC_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  982.329462] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to remove MAC context: -5
[  982.347832] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  982.347968] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MCAST_FILTER_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  982.347976] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: mcast filter cmd error. ret=-5
[  982.366245] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  982.366383] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MAC_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  982.366392] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to send MAC context (action:2): -5
[  982.366410] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to update MAC 7c:b0:c2:bc:f4:b7
[  982.384733] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  982.384849] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MAC_PM_POWER_TABLE: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  982.384857] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to update power mode
[  982.403331] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  982.403482] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending TXPATH_FLUSH: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  982.403487] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to send flush command (-5)
[  982.403490] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: flush request fail
[  984.404236] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: fail to flush all tx fifo queues Q 5
[  984.422625] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 154 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:2066 iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1f9/0x230 [iwlwifi]
[  984.422626] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 edac_mce_amd joydev ccp kvm snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd snd_seq_midi_event btusb cryptd btrtl snd_rawmidi amdgpu glue_helper uvcvideo btbcm btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops bluetooth videobuf2_v4l2 iwlmvm videobuf2_common snd_seq mac80211 libarc4 ecdh_generic input_leds amd_iommu_v2 videodev gpu_sched hp_wmi ecc mc ttm sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof snd_seq_device snd_timer iwlwifi drm_kms_helper k10temp fam15h_power i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops rtsx_pci_ms snd cfg80211 syscopyarea memstick sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev mac_hid hp_wireless tpm_infineon sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul
[  984.422701] RIP: 0010:iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0x1f9/0x230 [iwlwifi]
[  984.422736]  iwl_read_prph+0x39/0x90 [iwlwifi]
[  984.422751]  iwl_trans_pcie_log_scd_error+0x14c/0x220 [iwlwifi]
[  984.422771]  iwl_trans_pcie_wait_txq_empty+0x241/0x250 [iwlwifi]
[  984.422784]  iwl_trans_pcie_wait_txqs_empty+0x4c/0x70 [iwlwifi]
[  984.422804]  iwl_mvm_mac_flush+0x134/0x290 [iwlmvm]
[  984.423330]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_stop+0x2f/0x180 [iwlmvm]
[  984.423345]  _iwl_op_mode_stop.isra.0+0x31/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[  984.423355]  iwl_drv_stop+0x46/0x190 [iwlwifi]
[  984.423370]  iwl_pci_remove+0x1c/0x30 [iwlwifi]
[  984.423430] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
[  984.423435] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: iwlwifi device config registers:
[  984.423439] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Read failed at 0x0
[  984.478481] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Queue 5 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [2, 3] HW [90, 90] FH TRB=0x05a5a5a5a
[  984.496836] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.496951] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MAC_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.496962] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to send MAC context (action:2): -5
[  984.515084] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.515232] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending REPLY_BEACON_FILTERING_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.515431] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 154 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/mac80211.c:3153 iwl_mvm_mac_sta_state+0x458/0x6e0 [iwlmvm]
[  984.515440] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 edac_mce_amd joydev ccp kvm snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd snd_seq_midi_event btusb cryptd btrtl snd_rawmidi amdgpu glue_helper uvcvideo btbcm btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops bluetooth videobuf2_v4l2 iwlmvm videobuf2_common snd_seq mac80211 libarc4 ecdh_generic input_leds amd_iommu_v2 videodev gpu_sched hp_wmi ecc mc ttm sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof snd_seq_device snd_timer iwlwifi drm_kms_helper k10temp fam15h_power i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops rtsx_pci_ms snd cfg80211 syscopyarea memstick sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev mac_hid hp_wireless tpm_infineon sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul
[  984.515532] RIP: 0010:iwl_mvm_mac_sta_state+0x458/0x6e0 [iwlmvm]
[  984.516164]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_stop+0x2f/0x180 [iwlmvm]
[  984.516195]  _iwl_op_mode_stop.isra.0+0x31/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[  984.516203]  iwl_drv_stop+0x46/0x190 [iwlwifi]
[  984.516216]  iwl_pci_remove+0x1c/0x30 [iwlwifi]
[  984.534468] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.534685] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending ADD_STA_KEY: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.552819] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.552971] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending ADD_STA: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.553260] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 edac_mce_amd joydev ccp kvm snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd snd_seq_midi_event btusb cryptd btrtl snd_rawmidi amdgpu glue_helper uvcvideo btbcm btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops bluetooth videobuf2_v4l2 iwlmvm videobuf2_common snd_seq mac80211 libarc4 ecdh_generic input_leds amd_iommu_v2 videodev gpu_sched hp_wmi ecc mc ttm sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof snd_seq_device snd_timer iwlwifi drm_kms_helper k10temp fam15h_power i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops rtsx_pci_ms snd cfg80211 syscopyarea memstick sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev mac_hid hp_wireless tpm_infineon sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul
[  984.553845]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_stop+0x2f/0x180 [iwlmvm]
[  984.553875]  _iwl_op_mode_stop.isra.0+0x31/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[  984.553883]  iwl_drv_stop+0x46/0x190 [iwlwifi]
[  984.553895]  iwl_pci_remove+0x1c/0x30 [iwlwifi]
[  984.572054] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.572168] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.590461] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.590594] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MAC_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.590599] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to send MAC context (action:2): -5
[  984.590610] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to update MAC 7c:b0:c2:bc:f4:b7
[  984.608697] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.608912] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending REPLY_SF_CFG_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.609132] WARNING: CPU: 2 PID: 154 at drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/mvm/mac80211.c:2319 iwl_mvm_bss_info_changed_station+0x4a8/0x540 [iwlmvm]
[  984.609134] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep nls_iso8859_1 edac_mce_amd joydev ccp kvm snd_hda_codec_conexant snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg crct10dif_pclmul snd_hda_codec snd_hda_core ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hwdep snd_pcm aesni_intel snd_seq_midi crypto_simd snd_seq_midi_event btusb cryptd btrtl snd_rawmidi amdgpu glue_helper uvcvideo btbcm btintel videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops bluetooth videobuf2_v4l2 iwlmvm videobuf2_common snd_seq mac80211 libarc4 ecdh_generic input_leds amd_iommu_v2 videodev gpu_sched hp_wmi ecc mc ttm sparse_keymap serio_raw wmi_bmof snd_seq_device snd_timer iwlwifi drm_kms_helper k10temp fam15h_power i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops rtsx_pci_ms snd cfg80211 syscopyarea memstick sysfillrect sysimgblt soundcore hp_accel lis3lv02d input_polldev mac_hid hp_wireless tpm_infineon sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 rtsx_pci_sdmmc crc32_pclmul
[  984.609221] RIP: 0010:iwl_mvm_bss_info_changed_station+0x4a8/0x540 [iwlmvm]
[  984.609258]  iwl_mvm_bss_info_changed+0x75/0x1e0 [iwlmvm]
[  984.609796]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_stop+0x2f/0x180 [iwlmvm]
[  984.609831]  _iwl_op_mode_stop.isra.0+0x31/0x50 [iwlwifi]
[  984.609840]  iwl_drv_stop+0x46/0x190 [iwlwifi]
[  984.609852]  iwl_pci_remove+0x1c/0x30 [iwlwifi]
[  984.628094] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.628188] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending REMOVE_STA: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.628198] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to remove station. Id=0
[  984.628207] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to remove AP station
[  984.646320] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.646469] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending TIME_QUOTA_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.646474] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to send quota: -5
[  984.646477] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to update quotas
[  984.664673] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.664863] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MAC_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.664873] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to send MAC context (action:2): -5
[  984.664880] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to update MAC 7c:b0:c2:bc:f4:b7 (clear after unassoc)
[  984.682951] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.683062] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MAC_PM_POWER_TABLE: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.683068] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to update power mode
[  984.700927] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.701044] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending TIME_QUOTA_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.701052] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to send quota: -5
[  984.718899] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.719007] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending BINDING_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.719013] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to send binding (action:3): -5
[  984.737248] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.737457] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MAC_PM_POWER_TABLE: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.755505] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.755676] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MAC_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.755683] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to send MAC context (action:2): -5
[  984.755689] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: failed to update MAC 7c:b0:c2:bc:f4:b7
[  984.773858] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  984.774034] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending PHY_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  984.774040] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: PHY ctxt cmd error. ret=-5
[  986.776132] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: fail to flush all tx fifo queues Q 5
[  986.849001] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Queue 5 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [2, 3] HW [90, 90] FH TRB=0x05a5a5a5a
[  986.867771] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[  986.867954] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending MAC_CONTEXT_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[  986.867959] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to remove MAC context: -5
[  989.140426] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[  989.140923] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: HW_REV=0xFFFFFFFF, PCI issues?
[  989.160357] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

Comment: Is the Wi-Fi card driver installed?

Comment: Not sure where  I should look at I have added the lspci output while the wifi adapter was working in my original post. Its the third code block under " wifi adapter is working "

Comment: Is it a dual boot with Windows? If it is, disable Windows Fast Start feature. All is OK with the drivers.

Comment: It is not an dual boot.

Comment: It is pretty odd. Today I dont think I had issues with the wifi adapter, and I have not done anything to solve the problem .. Im kinda waiting for the problem to occur again so that I can do the same commands I used while the wifi adapter was working, with those results we could figure out the problem?

Comment: All looks good there.

Comment: wifi adapter not found again. dmesg | grep iwl gives me big error message I added the output in the question under " wifi adapter not found" 4th code block